# jQuery localScroll ajax breaks when using window.history.pushState

Tags: jquery, ajax, scrollto, pushstate

I've got a website where I'm using ajax to load each page of the site, primarily to switch between a blog page and a folio page. On the folio page, I'm using localScroll with the links in the sub-navigation.

This all works fine if the folio page is the initial page loaded. If any of the other pages on the site are loaded first, and I switch to the folio page, localScroll no longer works. Loading the folio page first, switching to another page, is fine.

I've worked backwards, and it seems that the issue only occurs if I use window.history.pushState (to change the url of the page). If I remove that, and leave everything else, localScroll works again.

I've even tried just adding window.history.pushState to the ajax demo that comes with localScroll and it happens there too.

Is there any reason why window.history.pushState might be breaking localScroll, and is there anyway to get it working again?

I've included a trimmed version of my code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nav-subnav').localScroll({
        lazy: true,
        target: scrolltarget
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', '#nav a', function() {
        pageLoad(this);
        return false; 
    });

});

function pageLoad(t){        
    //e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(t).prop('href');
    if ($link != window.location.href) {
        window.history.pushState({path:$link},'',$link);
        $('#content').add('#nav-submenu').animate({opacity: 0},500, function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: $link,
                success: function(content) {
                    var newTitle = $(content).filter('title').text();
                    document.title = newTitle;
                    $('#nav-subnav').html($(content).find('#nav-subnav .submenu'));
                    $('#content').html($(content).find('#content #wrapper'));
                    $('#content').add('#nav-subnav').animate({opacity: 1},500);
                 }
            }); 
        }); 
    }
    return false; 
};
```

Thanks in advance,
Nathan